# Rails Interactor rollbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using the [interactor gem](https://github.com/collectiveidea/interactor) in my rails project. When one of the interactors within the organizer fails, the rollback method is called. The question is, is there any way this method can be aware of why the interactor failed?

Example:

```
def call
  context.fail! error: 'Some error'
end

def rollback
  # I want to access 'Some error' here
end
```

Comment: The interactor gem hasn't been maintained for some time.  Is there any reason you don't want to use a transaction and add some custom error messages?

Comment: I could use transactions, but there are about 7 interactors in this one organizer so the gem removes a lot of the work. I also use interactors else where to remove code dup

Comment: @bkunzi01 afaik there are no new features, but gem seems to be completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just access the `context` inside `rollback` method. There is one catch - `rollback` of the "current" interactor won't be invoked. Take a look at the following code:

```
require "interactor"

class Foo
  include Interactor

  def call
  end

  def rollback
    p "#{context.error} from Foo"
  end
end

class Bar
  include Interactor

  def call
    context.fail!(error: "error!")
  end

  def rollback
    p "#{context.error} from Bar"
  end
end

class FooBar
  include Interactor::Organizer

  organize Foo, Bar
end

FooBar.call
```

it produces `"error! from Foo"` as the response. `Bar` throws an exception so `FooBar` organizer goes back to the `Foo` and calls its `rollback` method. `context` is shared so you have access to everything that was set before.